# Ubuntu installed on 2 different physical disks, how to get them on one grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, software-installation, ssd, bios

due to some disk issue, I had to give my drive for repair. So I installed ubuntu on my other drive. Now that drive has been fixed, how can i have both the ubuntu on a single grub?

Also is it a good idea to have ubuntu on my ssd drive, or better to use ubuntu installed on a HDD?

Comment: If both drives are connected, I'd expect a `sudo update-grub` to detect both disks (and any OS installed on them assuming it's readable & *clean* file-systems, ie. not hibenated/fastboot-windows or non-standard *fs* (BSD etc)).  As for *good idea* or *better* - it's personal choice & opinion; both have pros & cons (which aren't equal & can vary on the devices in question of which you provided no details).

Comment: SSDs are always faster *ergo* whenever possible install the OS in those, not in HDDs. You can use HDDs for data.

Comment: If one of the Ubuntu drives is a clone of the other you will have problems trying to boot them from one grub as the UUID's will be the same. If this is the case use GParted to change the UUID of one of the drives then check it's fstad and grub.cfg for UUID. After that run sudo update-grub` as guiverc says.